# swig and perl compilation errors

Tags: perl, swig

I'm new in Perl. I'm trying to create an extension for Perl in C++ using swig.

I downloaded and installed [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com) in windows. I just follow the "next" steps and finish the installation.
Strawberry library contains header files that swig `wrap.cxx` includes, like `EXTERN.h`, `perl.h` and `XSUB.h`.

When trying to run swig, it create the `wrap.cxx` file with compilation error.

This is my `module.i`

```
%module DocxFactory %{
   #include<string> 

   using namespace std;

   void printName(stringp_name
   {
      cout<<p_name;
   }
%}

%include "perl5\std_string.i";

void printName(string p_name);
```

Am I missing something? Maybe I need to do configuration steps for the Perl. I'm using Strawberry Perl (64-bit) 5.16.3.1-64bit.

Comment: what are the compilation errors?

Comment: I just indented the code in your `module.i` interface file. Did you notice you forgot the closing parenthesis in the definition of the `printName` function? May that be the cause of your problem?